# gc-expose effect in Node.js for long run application

Tags: javascript, node.js, garbage-collection

I have an issue with memory limit in my machine. So I have to push my memory usage in Node.js below 150MB. Therefore I run my application with `--gc-expose` parameter and called `global.gc()` in application each cycle.

So my question, is there any bad effect or deficiency if my app will run for long time ? FYI, I started this app with PM2.

Thanks

Comment: You may have performance issues if gc is not handled well. There is always a cost.    Are you also monitoring your memory inside the node.js application using memwatch?  This is a good article written byJohn McCutchan and I would like to share  [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/performance/mystery/)

Comment: at first I used memwatch to track which part of codes that consume most. But its likely because object (promise and array) aren't collected often. Thats why I forced GC to run each cycle in my code

Comment: I see why you are doing gc yourself now. So do you observe any performance hit when gc is working? or may be this is not an issue for your requirement.  There may be a reason why (promise and array) aren't collected often, they may belong to the old-space and  so V8 figure out this should not be done as often,  However, you have your own constrains and requirements, that may make sense for you. Will restructuring your code reduce memory usages or having gc to collect more often w/o impacting performance will be a good area to check.

Comment: [link] (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/performance/mystery/)  This great article by John McCutchan will give some insights and I enjoy it very much. Hope that you like it too. But since it was published in 2013, things may have been changed or enhanced.